# FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT event's relatedObject always null

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to code a drop-down control in as3, where clicking on the control's 'top-text' (a Sprite) causes a box to appear (another Sprite). The box contains a list of all items that may be selected. When 'item1' is selected the box closes and item1-text becomes the control's top-text. And so on.

I also want the box to automatically close when the control loses focus, i.e. when the user clicks anywhere else on the flash movie. For this, I add an event listener on the box for FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT.

The thing is, I want different processing to take place depending on the FocusEvent's relatedObject. To be more precise I want to do something more than just closing in the specific case where relatedObject is a child of the drop-down control itself. And just close it if not.

My problem is that the relatedObject property is **always** coming up null no matter what gains focus. Furthermore the isRelatedObjectInaccessible property is always false so (according to the documentation) it is not a security related problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this behavior is caused by the [Doomsday Console](http://code.google.com/p/doomsday-console-64/) which was added to the stage as part of the project I was working on. Removing it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to use flash.events.MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN intead of FOCUS_OUT. handle it on the clip under the control.

Comment: True, I could always track clicks 'outside' the control by adding a MOUSE_DOWN listener on the stage. It wouldn't track keyboard navigation though, such as the tab key.